# From controller to view hello in Java Spring Mvc 2022.0

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, view, controller

premise: sorry for my english

Hi everyone, I'm at the beginning and I'm trying to take the first steps towards the world of Spring Mvc in Java. From the different tutorials they have come to create a page in jsp, to create a page in the controller. But I can't get the message from the controller to the view.

hello.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page due</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2>${nome}</h2>
        <h1>Message : <span th:text="${nome}"></span></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package = "controllerHello" />
    
    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="hello.htm">helloController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
<bean name="helloController" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="hello" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

helloController.java

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package = "controllerHello" />
    
    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="hello.htm">helloController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
<bean name="helloController" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="hello" />
</beans>
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Because the page is visible

Comment: You are combining the wrong things. First I would strongly suggest to stop using JSP. That is pretty legacy and not really updated anymore (only maintenace). In your JSP you are also trying to use Thymeleaf, don't either stick with proper JSP (I suggested against it) or indeed do use Thymeleaf properly. As you are learning new technologies I would also strongly advice to use Spring Boot, which will save you a ton on setup.

Comment: Very first thing Thanks that you answered me. Thymeleaf I know I wrote it wrong. Can you give me an example or if you have an example on how to set up the page? Spring Boot not now, but thanks for the advice

Comment: Please post the code of helloController. You posted some xml code.